# what is the advantage of using classes instead of directly use GUI controls values

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, oop, webforms

i have a scenario of user management form.

The user have following textboxes (`txt_fname`, `txt_lname`, `txt_email`, ..etc) and some other information.

Why some programmers are using a class to hold the user information and then save this class to database?

There is the possibility to save the information directly from reading the values from the controls (textboxes) and send them to DB. Why using a class first ?

i would like to ask what is the advantage of using class in such situations. Like : `users`, `Products`

Comment: this is a very board topic, try google 'MVC', then read some articles first.

Comment: I am not using MVC. i am still using the classical one. but do you think it has any advantage ?

Comment: @Matt Why he needs to read about MVC? Am missing that

Comment: From wikipedia: Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architectural pattern for implementing user interfaces. It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts, so as to separate internal representations of information from the ways that information is presented to or accepted from the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good approach to seperate layers/components/classes, that does not have strong connection (Loose Coupling).

The reason is that if you need change view or reuse user, you are not limited by the strong connection of "view" and "model" class.

For example, if you want to take the user and use him in another application, you just take that class and you are done. If you are "strong-connected" to view, there is no easy way.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply. It means using class in such situation (Single WinForm) is not so much usefull. But crossing through forms and views, class is very appropriat way to hold data. is that right so far ?

Comment: Exactly, the bigger the application is, the more important it is.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why you would want to use a class to represent database objects, a few of which are:

1. Layers of separation between the database and client application (greater security)
2. Data validation (make sure fields are input in the correct format)
3. Reusable interface for objects, so that changes in the database don't require a complete rewrite of the client page

You can do a lot of research on MVVM which might show you some other benefits of using classes.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply, you mean separation between client interface and database using a class is a great security. So if the data is validated during the input, so which rule does the class play in such situation ?

Comment: Similar to what @libik said, if you were to reuse this type of input across your site then you would write the validation into the class properties so that any changes to requirements were updated everywhere at once. For example, if you suddenly decided that you would only allow email addresses ending in ".com", adding that validation to the class property would update validation across the entire site.

Comment: Thanks a lot RemedialBear. nice example. So i can use classes principle also for data validation. right ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many benefits to use class :

- the isolation of the logic of the program and the interface (you can change the GUI as you wish and the logic stay rigid).
- the reusing of code you can use the code anywhere (desktop , Web , console).
- the class may used by may by many  scenarios not just your form.
- easy to debug when isolate the GUI and the program logic.
  the re command you to read more about OOP .
  Check out this links:
  http://wiki.tcl.tk/13398
  https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa12/notes/06.1_OOP/Advantages.html?CurrentSlide=3